# Any way to have delegatecall change the delegate contract's storage state?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, eoa

A delegatecall'ed function executes inside of the delegatecaller contract's own memory & storage context.

But I'm wondering whether the following is in any way possible (i.e. if certain access modifiers are used):

EOA msg.sender calls contractA.method(), 
contractA.method() delegatecalls to contractB.(), 
contractB.method() runs. (Somehow?) ContractB's 'mapping (address => bool) approve;' is updated to include msg.sender[true].

Answer (score 1):

The method on the delegate contract should be able to make `call` to a different method on the same contract which should put it in the context of the delegate contract